# Artifactory docker image cannot mount volume that is using S3FS Docker volume plug-in

Tags: docker, artifactory

I am trying to get artifactory-oss docker image running in AWS ECS.  And I would like to keep the datastore in S3.

I am using [rexray/s3fs](https://hub.docker.com/r/rexray/s3fs/) to make the S3 bucket available as a volume to the artifactory container.

The docker instance exits shortly after it starts.  The error in the log say:

> ERROR: '/var/opt/jfrog/artifactory' is not a directory

So, did some investigating.

When I start the artifactory image as follows:

```
docker run -it --entrypoint=/bin/bash -v vol-artifactory:/artifactory -p 8081:8081  docker.bintray.io/jfrog/artifactory-oss:latest
```

I see the following:

> d?????????   ? ?    ?        ?            ? artifactory

But when start the docker instance using a Centos Image as follows:

```
docker run -it -v vol-artifactory:/artifactory centos
```

I have no problems seeing the the mounted volume:

```
drwx------   1 1030 1030     0 Feb 10  2018 artifactory
```

Any idea what could be going on with the artifactory image?

Comment: You getting an error message pointing to `/var/opt/jfrog/artifactory` where you mounted your volume on `/artifactory`.

Comment: Yea, sorry.  The error message was when artifactory was trying to come up.  The mounting to /artifactory was me just testing to see if I could mount the volume and see the content.